# Fit a curve (spline?) through a solid in 3D and map a value onto it

Tags: multivariate-analysis

I have a series of xyz data in a unit cube.  It forms a sort of tapered & curved cylinder.  It will begin and end at 0,0,0 and 1,1,1.  I want some sort of best fit curve down the 'axis' of this shape.  And I need to take a new xyz point and map/project it onto this best fit curve.  If I was expecting a straight line, I'd use the first principal component, but in this case I'm almost certain that I want some kind of 3d spline.  I'm not after a fit to the surface.  To be clear, there is no response variable; it's just xyz data points, so a model is not what I need.

Can someone give me some suggestions for the name of what I want to do?  I need some keywords to get me going.  I'm working in `R` so if you can suggest a package even better.  Alternatively, perhaps something in `Matlab` would work. But mostly I need to know what this process is called.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a principal curve. In R try the **princurve** package based on Trevor Hastie's original code. The **cems** package  would be worth a look too as it fits principal curves via a different approach, but it has been archived on CRAN (or was last time I looked) because it was failing checks there. **cems** is still there but you need to build it yourself.

You can look at a description of principal curves in Hastie et al (2010) Elements of Statistical Learning on page 541. The [PDF is freely available](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/).